# Hiding Toolbar with Swipe Actions

Tags: java, android, animation, swipe

I am trying to use an animation for that hides and shows a `toolbar` by detecting swiping gestures.It works but the issue is that when the `toolbar` is there(visible) it will repeat if you swipe up again and again and again. How can I prevent this from happening? I've try using variable to count each step then reset at the ending but that does not work either. Helping me past this would save a lot more time I've been stuck here for 2 weeks now.

**CoreActivity.java**

```
//Swipe Events WebSwipe
    WebSwipe = new Swipe(350, 700);
    WebSwipe.setListener(new SwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSwipingLeft(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedLeft(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipingRight(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedRight(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipingUp(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedUp(final MotionEvent event) {
            Animation ToolbarGone = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this, R.anim.m_toolbar_gone);
            m_Toolbar.startAnimation(ToolbarGone);



        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipingDown(final MotionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipedDown(final MotionEvent event) {
               Animation ToolbarVisible = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this, R.anim.m_toolbar_visible);
                m_Toolbar.startAnimation(ToolbarVisible);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility` of `view`

if it is `visible` don't start animation.

Use `animation listeners`, so that you can set your view `visibility` to `GONE`

Comment: This seems like it is most likely to work but with the if(m_Toolbar.getvisiability() == View.Visible) &  the same for Gone it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code::

Add `boolean` to manage swipe gesture.

```
private boolean isSwipeUp=falese;


 //Swipe Events WebSwipe
 WebSwipe = new Swipe(350, 700);
 WebSwipe.setListener(new SwipeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSwipingLeft(final MotionEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedLeft(final MotionEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipingRight(final MotionEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedRight(final MotionEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipingUp(final MotionEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedUp(final MotionEvent event) {

        if(!isSwipeUp)
        {
            Animation ToolbarGone = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this, R.anim.m_toolbar_gone);
            m_Toolbar.startAnimation(ToolbarGone);
            isSwipeUp = true;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipingDown(final MotionEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipedDown(final MotionEvent event) {
           Animation ToolbarVisible = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CoreActivity.this, R.anim.m_toolbar_visible);
            m_Toolbar.startAnimation(ToolbarVisible);
            isSwipeUp = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You can also do it as **Balu Sangem** suggested.just use view visibility instead of **isSwipeUp** flag.